# Why am I able to scrape only certain images from a url and not others?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, attributes, keyerror

This is the first question I'm asking on stackoverflow, so this process is just as much of a learning experience as the question I'm asking. Any tips/tricks on this would also be appriciated.

I'm using `beautifulsoup` in `python` to scrape images from wiki. There are a total of 18 pictures, but I am only able to scrape less than that. For example, I cannot scrape `image[0]` or `image[1]`, but I can scrape `image[2]`. I am getting a `KeyError` when looking for the `src` attribute, but each image has an `src` attribute.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
import requests
import bs4
res = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subaru_Outback")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
subaru = soup.select('.thumbimage')
image_url = subaru[0]
image_url['src']
```

When I run the code on `image_url = subaru[0]` and `image_url = subaru[1]`, I get the keyError: 'src'. However, when I run the code on `image_url = subaru[2]`, the code runs fine.

These are the results for soup.select('.thumbimage')[0,1,2]:

`soup.select('.thumbimage')[0]`
<div class="thumbimage"><a class="image" href="/wiki/File:1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon_--*03-16-2012_front.JPG"><img alt="" data-file-height="1012" data-file-width="1763" decoding="async" height="115" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon*--*03-16-2012_front.JPG/200px-1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon*--*03-16-2012_front.JPG" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon*--*03-16-2012_front.JPG/300px-1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon*--*03-16-2012_front.JPG 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon*--*03-16-2012_front.JPG/400px-1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon*--_03-16-2012_front.JPG 2x" width="200"/></a></div>

`soup.select('.thumbimage')[1]`
<div class="thumbimage"><a class="image" href="/wiki/File:1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon_--*03-16-2012_rear.JPG"><img alt="" data-file-height="708" data-file-width="1328" decoding="async" height="107" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon*--*03-16-2012_rear.JPG/200px-1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon*--*03-16-2012_rear.JPG" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon*--*03-16-2012_rear.JPG/300px-1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon*--*03-16-2012_rear.JPG 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon*--*03-16-2012_rear.JPG/400px-1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon*--_03-16-2012_rear.JPG 2x" width="200"/></a></div>

`soup.select('.thumbimage')[2]`
<img class="thumbimage" data-file-height="1152" data-file-width="1536" decoding="async" height="165" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/New_Car_-*Exterior*%286879842774%29.jpg/220px-New_Car_-*Exterior*%286879842774%29.jpg" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/New_Car_-*Exterior*%286879842774%29.jpg/330px-New_Car_-*Exterior*%286879842774%29.jpg 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/New_Car_-*Exterior*%286879842774%29.jpg/440px-New_Car_-*Exterior*%286879842774%29.jpg 2x" width="220"/>

As you can see, there are 'src' attributes for each image. I do notice that subaru[0] and subaru[1] have "div" at the beginning of the output, whereas subaru[2] has "img". subaru[2] is in fact the 3rd image in the wiki article. I don't understand why I'm getting a KeyError: 'src' for an image that has and 'src' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here that your selector instead of `<img>` only get the `<div>` in your first two examples and this do not have a `src` attribute so following would be closer:

```
soup.select('img.thumbimage')
```

From the docs:

> KeyError: [attr] - Caused by accessing tag['attr'] when the tag in
> question doesn’t define the attr attribute. The most common errors are
> KeyError: 'href' and KeyError: 'class'. Use tag.get('attr') if you’re
> not sure attr is defined, just as you would with a Python dictionary.

You could select your elements also more specific for example based on parts of their `src`:

```
soup.select('img[src*="commons/thumb/"]')
```

###### Example

```
import requests
import bs4
res = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subaru_Outback")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for e in soup.select('img[src*="commons/thumb/"]'):
    print(e.get('src'))
```

###### Output

```
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/2020_Subaru_Outback_AWD%2C_front.jpg/280px-2020_Subaru_Outback_AWD%2C_front.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon_--_03-16-2012_front.JPG/200px-1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon_--_03-16-2012_front.JPG
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon_--_03-16-2012_rear.JPG/200px-1st_Subaru_Legacy_wagon_--_03-16-2012_rear.JPG
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/New_Car_-_Exterior_%286879842774%29.jpg/220px-New_Car_-_Exterior_%286879842774%29.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/1998_Subaru_Outback_%28BG9_MY98%29_Special_Edition_station_wagon_%282010-09-23%29_01.jpg/200px-1998_Subaru_Outback_%28BG9_MY98%29_Special_Edition_station_wagon_%282010-09-23%29_01.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/10/1998_Subaru_Outback_%28BG9_MY98%29_Special_Edition_station_wagon_%282010-09-23%29_02.jpg/200px-1998_Subaru_Outback_%28BG9_MY98%29_Special_Edition_station_wagon_%282010-09-23%29_02.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/19/2001_Subaru_Outback_%28BH9_MY02%29_Limited_station_wagon_%282011-04-02%29_01.jpg/200px-2001_Subaru_Outback_%28BH9_MY02%29_Limited_station_wagon_%282011-04-02%29_01.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/2001_Subaru_Outback_%28BH9_MY02%29_Limited_station_wagon_%282011-04-02%29_02.jpg/200px-2001_Subaru_Outback_%28BH9_MY02%29_Limited_station_wagon_%282011-04-02%29_02.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/2006-2009_Subaru_Outback_2.5i_station_wagon_%282011-11-17%29_01.jpg/200px-2006-2009_Subaru_Outback_2.5i_station_wagon_%282011-11-17%29_01.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/2006-2009_Subaru_Outback_2.5i_station_wagon_%282011-11-17%29_02.jpg/200px-2006-2009_Subaru_Outback_2.5i_station_wagon_%282011-11-17%29_02.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Subaru_Outback_%28BR%29_manufactured_2010_2457cc_%282%29.jpg/200px-Subaru_Outback_%28BR%29_manufactured_2010_2457cc_%282%29.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/2011_Subaru_Outback_%28BR9_MY11%29_2.5i_station_wagon_%282015-07-14%29_02.jpg/200px-2011_Subaru_Outback_%28BR9_MY11%29_2.5i_station_wagon_%282015-07-14%29_02.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/2018_Subaru_Outback_SE_Premium_Symmetrical_AWD_2.5_Front.jpg/200px-2018_Subaru_Outback_SE_Premium_Symmetrical_AWD_2.5_Front.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/2018_Subaru_Outback_SE_Premium_Symmetrical_AWD_2.5_Rear.jpg/200px-2018_Subaru_Outback_SE_Premium_Symmetrical_AWD_2.5_Rear.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c1/2021_Subaru_Outback_Limited%2C_front_3.17.21.jpg/200px-2021_Subaru_Outback_Limited%2C_front_3.17.21.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f0/2021_Subaru_Outback_Limited%2C_rear_3.17.21.jpg/200px-2021_Subaru_Outback_Limited%2C_rear_3.17.21.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/1st-Subaru-Outback-Sport.jpg/220px-1st-Subaru-Outback-Sport.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/2002-2003_Subaru_Outback_Sport.jpg/220px-2002-2003_Subaru_Outback_Sport.jpg
//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/3rd_Subaru_Impreza_Outback_Sport.jpg/220px-3rd_Subaru_Impreza_Outback_Sport.jpg
```

Comment: Why was I getting a KeyError when subaru[0] and subaru[1] clearly had 'src' attributes?

Comment: Issue here that your selector instead of `<img>` only get the `<div>` and this do not have a `src` attribute